# Jersey City Journal Square PATH parking - how do I make a reservation?

Tags: bookings, automobiles, new-york-city, train-stations, new-jersey

I am planning on driving to NYC, and staying in Jersey City to reduce costs.

I will be driving from my hotel to the Journal Square PATH Station to get into Manhattan everyday.

[On the PATH website](http://www.panynj.gov/path/journal-square-station.html), it says parking is provided by LAZ parking nearby.

But at the LAZ parking website all I get is an info page, and nothing about reservations or costs.

https://www.lazparking.com/local/jersey-city-nj/journal-square---path-garage

Can anyone provide insight as to whether this parking facility commonly fills up, as well as prices. On lazparking.com it does not give a rate for this parking lot.

I am just concerned that if it fills up, it could make for severe complications in my plans.

Comment: There are around [half a dozen garages](http://en.parkopedia.com/parking/journal_square_jersey_city/) within a few blocks of Journal Square. I would rethink your strategy, though. Parking is not cheap in Jersey City, and traffic will be something of a headache. A NJ Transit bus to the PATH, or to the ferry terminals at Weehawken or Hoboken might be better.

Comment: I want to be able to get back from Manhattan to my hotel at any time. I don't want to be waiting at a bus stop at Midnight. In addition, the bus just adds another step in the process. The PATH from Journal square to WorldTrade runs often and all night, I don't think the ferry does. I just want the most reliable option.

Comment: @choster the ferry service in Hoboken is infrequent, and the bus station is at the Hoboken PATH station (as are the light rail and conventional rail stations).  I work there and the few times I've though of taking the ferry the next departure was more than one hour away.  If the schedule matches yours, it might be worthwhile.  The ferry also costs a lot more than the PATH.

Comment: Internet searches suggest that a few years ago the cost was $7 for 12 hours.  It may have changed.  The facility apparently takes reservations; if you have one, you're guaranteed to have a space available.

Comment: I updated the initial post to reflect my confusion about reservations.

Comment: I suspect you may need to create an account to get information about making reservations.  I didn't create an account, though, so I haven't tested that hypothesis.  If I were you I'd try that and then, if that didn't work, call the phone number.

Comment: I can't think of many things that are less fun that driving in Jersey City/NYC. I would just spend a few bucks on an Uber to get to/from the station. You can order them at any time of the day and two trips would cost less than parking your car.

Comment: Why is driving in Jersey City so bad? Google says it is a 15 minute drive down Tonnele ave.

Comment: @ScottF When there is no traffic.  On a weekday that's basically before 8am or after 8pm.  And where is your hotel?  There may be better options.  And if you're looking to go PATH route the better station to Park at would be Harrison, Exchange Place or Pavonia Newport.

Comment: @Karlson are you speaking from experience? The parking at Exchange Place and Newport could be much more expensive. Also, how do you know the Google estimate isn't already taking traffic into account? It gives estimates both ways, and you don't know where the hotel is.

Comment: @ScottF your estimation tells us nothing as we don't know the departure point. However it's not just about travel time, but also about the constant heavy traffic, the unexpected wrong turns down one way streets, and people generally driving like maniacs that I dislike about driving in JC.

Comment: @phoog Yes.  I am speaking from experience.  I've lived in Jersey City for 5 years and have to drive through it on multiple occasions since then and Google doesn't estimate the traffic cost correctly when driving through the city.  I may not know where the hotel is but I know where Tonnele ave is and where the hotels on Tonnele are.  Further, the parking at JS may be slightly less expensive but I've found it overly burdensome to use to get into the city as compared to Harrison, Exchange Place, or Pavonia (where you can park at the mall)

Comment: The candidate hotel is Holiday Inn express Tonnele ave. It says here that parking at the mall is $22 a day...http://denisonparking.com/find-parking/jersey-city/14

Comment: @ScottF Gone up a little bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LAZ have an online reservation system [on their website](https://www.lazparking.com/local/venues/16-Path-Plaza-Jersey-City-NJ-07306-USA), however it seems to be unavailable for that particular location. However a different site called [Parkopedia](http://en.parkopedia.com/parking/garage/journal_square_path_garage/07306/jersey_city/) lists their price list:

[image: path parking price list]

Parkopedia shows numerous alternative parking spots in that area, so you shouldn't have an issue finding a spot:

[image: path station parking lots]

Comment: Dammit I was working on this!

Comment: @JoErNanO bounty... DENIED! *maniacal laughter*

Comment: Pwned! Dominating! Godlike!

Comment: It might be a good idea to type the price list into a table for various reasons (readability, images can't be searched, heck if someone wanted to translate the page).